# void Funtion(String) can't be assigned to void Funtion(String?)?

Tags: flutter, forms, validation, dart-null-safety

```
Widget _buildName(){
   return TextFormField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
     validator: (String value){
       if(value.isEmpty){
         return 'Name is Required';
       }
     },
     onSaved: (String value){
       _name = value;
     }
   );
}
```

Comment: What do you exact want?

Answer (score 2):

If you check `onSaved` and `validator` methods, both provide nullable string

- `FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved,`
- `FormFieldValidator<String>? validator,`

So it will be

```dart
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
        validator: (String? value) {
          // add other condition
          if (value == null) {
            return 'Name is Required';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (String? value) {
            _name = value; 
        });
```

More about [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)